# trying to convert excel file which contains images and auto filter along the headers into html using python

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert excel file which contains images and auto filter along the headers into html using python. I was able to convert the excel to html using the following code.
There are 2 problems 1 the images are not aligned with the cells and there is no auto filters in converted file. i'm open to use python or HTML JavaScript. Any help will be appreciated.

```
from xlsx2html import xlsx2html
xlsx2html("in_put.xlsx", "out_put.html")
```

Comment: To support filtering and sorting akin to Excel, you likely need a library to extend your tables. Maybe something like https://datatables.net/